# Python 2.7 subprocess with unicode path

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, subprocess

I have been suffered with UnicodeEncodeError for days.
I search some articles but all of them are not working.
I tried like that

```
command = u'start C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select, "C:/한글.txt"'
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 614, in _execute_child
    args = '{} /c "{}"'.format (comspec, args)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 43-45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I solve the problem?

### MY SOLUTION

I've been trapped in complex case.
To run unicode path, I have to use "**cp949**" encoding and **os.realpath** as below

```
path = os.path.realpath("C:/한글.txt")    ## realpath
command = u'start C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select, "{}"'.format(path)
command = command.encode("cp949")         ## encoding: cp949
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding the string (eg. with the system default encoding) before passing it to Popen?

Answer (score 0):

**In case of Python2.7:**

You should define source code encoding, add this to the top of your script:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

The reason why it works differently in console and in the IDE is, likely, because of different default encodings set. You can check it by running:

```
import sys
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

**Complete Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import subprocess
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
command = u'echo "C:/한글.txt"'
subprocess.Popen(command.encode('utf-8'), shell=True)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python test.py 
ascii
C:/한글.txt
```

---

**In case of Python3:**

You should encode it to `utf-8`. I have tried it and it worked as expected.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
command = u'echo "C:/한글.txt"'
subprocess.Popen(command.encode('utf-8'), shell=True)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
C:/한글.txt
```